# Numbers fill color

Tags: macos, numbers

In Numbers is there a way to set a fill color to repeatedly select for random cells, such as in Excel? I am not looking for a conditional formatting.  I would like to color fill any cell I choose without having to go into the cell fill option and re-select the color for each individual cell.

Comment: As in copying and pasting format?

Comment: I just want to be able to "save" and re-use a fill color repeatedly without having to re-select the color every time I want to fill a particular cell.  In Excel you can select a color that shows in the tool bar to be used repeatedly until you select a different color or no-fill.

Comment: Assuming Numbers for macOS not iOS? What version?  Although what you want may or may not be possible, this information is helpful for those helping to find a solution.

Comment: Numbers version 4.3.1 for macOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Numbers handles formatting differently from Excel, it is possible to apply the cell style to additional cells without going back to the color picker.  Note that this applies *all* styles from the original cell.  This method pastes *only* the styling *not* the data. It will have no affect on the actual data in the cell.

Apply your selected color to a cell.  If there is other formatting you wish to apply and repeat, do so.  (Bold text, borders etc)

- Select the formatted cell and then copy the format [Format > Copy Style] or <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
- Select the cell(s) you wish to apply the formatting to then paste the formatting [Format > Paste Style] <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

Alternatively, one can add buttons to the toolbar as well.

[image: Copy Paste Style]

[image: Paste formatting]

Comment: I'm confused...I have existing data in cells which needs to remain, so how do I copy/paste only the color, not the cell contents?  Duh - I think I just figured it out - thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, this does not paste the contents. Only the formatting.